# gtsummary modify_table_styling in multiple rows

Tags: gtsummary

I am attempting to modify the indentation of multiple rows in gtsummary. How can I select multiple rows under "rows"?

ex.

this works:

```
df1 %>%
tbl_summary(
  )%>%
modify_table_styling(
  columns = label,
  rows = variable == "var1",
text_format = "indent2")
```

this doesn't:

```
df1 %>%
tbl_summary(
  )%>%
modify_table_styling(
  columns = label,
  rows = variable == c("var1","var2")
text_format = "indent2")
```

Thanks

Comment: Use  `variable %in% c("var1","var2")` :)